# Angular NgXs - action is being triggered the other action

Tags: angular, ngxs

I have two actions:

- CountriesGetList
- CitiesGetList

and a component which dispatches an action within its constructor:

`this.store.dispatch(new CountriesGetList({ object: this.object, objectId: this.objectId }));`

and the issue is that this dispatch triggers this action @Action(CountriesGetList) and...the other action:

```
@Action(CitiesGetList)
columns_get_list({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<StateModel>, action: CitiesGetList) {}
```

And the question is: why does this happen? I don't need to dispatch the second action - @Action(CitiesGetList).

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will need more info to be able to reproduce, but the most logical explanation for this would be that you use the same `static type` value for both actions. So I guess you have them declared like this:

```
export class CountriesGetList {
  static type = '[Countries] Get List';
  // ...
}

export class CitiesGetList{
  static type = '[Countries] Get List';
  // ...
}
```

You should update your cities action to have a unique type property:

```
export class CitiesGetList{
  static type = '[Cities] Get List';
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was the issue -  static type = '[Cities] Get List'; I've changed all the types and now this works like a charm.
Thanks Poul, you saved my life! )))